# Signal handler triggers on first time signal is raised, but not subsequent times

Tags: c, linux, sockets, signals

I'm fairly new to signals. It's an AF_INET socket, handling SIGIO. The first connection and packet are received and handled (displayed) properly, as far as I can tell.

Subsequent sends are not, however. A breakpoint on the signal handler in GDB (as well as the atomic state flag) shows that the signal handler is never raised again when packets are sent.

Relevant portions of my code (sections missing):

```
char buffer[1024];
volatile sig_atomic_t data_waiting = 0;
struct sigaction saio;

// [...] Socket setup and accept

saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
saio.sa_flags = 0; 
saio.sa_restorer = NULL;

sigemptyset(&saio.sa_mask);
sigaddset(&saio.sa_mask, SIGINT);

sigaction(SIGIO, &saio, NULL);

fcntl(connected_sockfd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl(connected_sockfd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);

while(run_main)
{   
    usleep(500);

    if(data_waiting == 1)
    {
        data_waiting = 0;
        bytes = read(connected_sockfd, buffer, 1023);

        if(bytes > 0)
        {
            buffer[bytes] = 0; // null termination
            printf("Message: %s\n", buffer);
            buffer[0] = 0; // "reset" string
        }
    }
}
```

and my handler:

```
void signal_handler_IO(int status)
{
    data_waiting = 1;
}
```

I have nearly the same code handling SIGIO on a serial port file descriptor with zero issues, so I'm really stumped. I assumed the handler would be installed identically, but I might be wrong there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
You've done a thorough job on minimizing, but it was probably too thorough.  We certainly can't compile what you show.  You've also not explained how the data is being sent — how you know that there is more data on the socket, or how the packets are being sent.  Why do you think it is a good idea to be using SIGIO?  Why not simply wait and read?  Or use one of the poll functions (`select()`, `poll()`, maybe `epoll()`, etc)?

Comment: To properly debug this, I'd 1st of all add *complete* logging *and* handling or what `read()` returns. Log the value of  `bytes` and also stop reading if `0` is returned, as this indicated that the other side closed the connection. Also better log byte wise, just in case a "stray" `'\0'` inside the chunk is received which in turn made `printf()` ignore to print anything after this `'\0'`.